# How to concatenate several MvcHtmlString instances

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, html-helper, mvchtmlstring

I have some doubts about how to concatenate MvcHtmlString instances because of this information found in [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.mvchtmlstring.aspx) :

> **MvcHtmlString Class** Represents an HTML-encoded string that
>   should not be encoded again

Do I risk that strings are HTML-encoded twice when using code like this:

```
var label = Html.LabelFor(model => model.Email);
var textbox = Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Email);
var validation = Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Email);

var result = MvcHtmlString.Create(
  label.ToString() + textbox.ToString() + validation.ToString());
```

(note: this is supposed to go into an HtmlHelper extension method to reduce code-duplication in views).

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Your code is correct.

That snippet from MSDN means that an encoding View Engine (such as the Aspx view engine in .NET 4 when using `<%: %>` or the Razor view engine in MVC 3) should not re-encode the string value of the object.

So for example:

```
string s = "<tag>";
var hs = MvcHtmlString.Create(s);

<%: s %>  -- outputs "&lt;tag&gt;"
<%: hs %> -- outputs "<tag>"
```

Answer (score 60):

Too bad C# won't let us override the + operator here! How about using an extension method instead?

```
public static MvcHtmlString Concat(this MvcHtmlString first, params MvcHtmlString[] strings)
{
    return MvcHtmlString.Create(first.ToString() + string.Concat(strings.Select(s => s.ToString())));
}
```

This could probably be optimized, but you can run with it. It should be fairly trivial to prove that this doesn't double encode strings with a unit test.

Usage sample:

```
label.Concat(textbox, validation)
```

And now a shameless plug for my blog: [Use TagBuilder or HtmlTags to clean up your HTML](http://geekswithblogs.net/ryanohs/archive/2010/04/21/a-semantic-model-for-html-tagbuilder-and-htmltags.aspx)

Comment: This doesn't compile for me, I've changed it:
 public static MvcHtmlString Concat(this MvcHtmlString first, params MvcHtmlString[] strings)
 {
  return MvcHtmlString.Create(first.ToString() + string.Concat(strings.Select(s => s.ToString()).ToArray()));
 }

Comment: is there a reason the input params aren't `IHtmlString`?

Comment: IHtmlString didn't exist in .NET 3.5

Answer (score 21):

I went for this approach:

```
    private static MvcHtmlString Concat(params MvcHtmlString[] items)
    {
        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (var item in items.Where(i => i != null))
            sb.Append(item.ToHtmlString());
        return MvcHtmlString.Create(sb.ToString());
    }
```

It's just a utility method that I use inside the classes with extension methods for HtmlHelper.

Answer (score 4):

I know this is super old, but yet another way (which I find to be more elegant), is to use an overload of the String method Concat, which metadata definition is

```
public static String Concat(params object[] args);
```

that basically ToStrings each one of the objects passed in and then concatenates the results and returns the concatenated string.

So the final result would be:

```
var result = MvcHtmlString.Create(
    string.Concat(
        label, textbox, validation
    )
);
```