# Appending text to a MvcHtmlString in Razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

Trying to use a loop to build a series of table rows in Razor:

```
MvcHtmlString filesList = MvcHtmlString.Create("");
foreach (var file in orderRow.Files)
{
    fileList = fileList + "<tr><td  colspan='2'><a href='http://@file.Location/file.FileName' target='_blank'>@file.Description </a></td></tr>";
}
    @filesList
}
```

[How to concatenate several MvcHtmlString instances](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3460762/how-to-concatenate-several-mvchtmlstring-instances) leads me to think i'm on the right track with the above code but i'm working against Razor an am experiencing different mileage.

thx

Comment: You cannot use Razor syntax in a normal string.  You need to manually concatenate **and escape** your objects.

Comment: In this case you're building a big string and then immediately outputting it.  If this is the real code, don't bother to build a string, just write the output.

Comment: Are you writing a normal method or are you in a Razor page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're over-complicating the problem.  You don't need to build a string at all for your situation, since you're just outputting the string directly after the loop.  You can do this:

```
@foreach (var file in orderRow.Files) {
    <tr><td  colspan='2'><a href='http://@file.Location/file.FileName' target='_blank'>@file.Description </a></td></tr>
}
```

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/12/15/asp-net-mvc-3-razor-s-and-lt-text-gt-syntax.aspx

Answer (score 2):

**Assuming you're writing a static method in a `.cs` file**:

There's no point.
`MvcHtmlString` doesn't actually escape anything; it justs tells Razor / ASPX not to escape itself.

You should assemble your string normally using a `StringBuilder`, then return `new HtmlString(builder.ToString())`.

If you're in a Razor page, the whole thing is pointless; see the other answer.